# storage size of isn't known : enum

Tags: c, enums

I have an enum defined in file1.h. I want to refer this enum as an argument in another file file2.h without including file1.h. Now I have to call get_color() function from file3.h. I am getting two different types of error:

1. passing argument 1 of 'get_color' from  incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
2. Error 1 is resolved, but I get a different error: storage size of col isn't known.

The only issue is I cannot include file1.h in file2.h. Please suggest how I could resolve the issue.

file1.h

```
typedef enum {
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN2,
} colors_t;
```

file2.h

```
void get_color(enum colors_t *col);
```

file3.h //option 1

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h" 
int main()
{
     colors_t col;
     get_color(&col); //error: passing argument 1 of 'get_color' from   incompatible pointer type [-Werror]

}
```

file3.h //option 2

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h" 
int main()
{
     enum colors_t col;
     get_color(&col); //error: storage size of col isn't known.

}
```

Comment: I may be wrong but that's not how typedef works.  It is `colors_t` that becomes the type, not `enum colors_t`.  Just like with structs.

Comment: Note that should be `file3.c` or `main.c`, not `file3.h`. If you have function definitions in a file, it's probably not a header.

Comment: If you want to use both `enum colors_t` and `colors_t`, write: `typedef enum colors_t {
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN2,
} colors_t;`.  Otherwise, choose one and stick with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of `get_colors` should be...

```
void get_color(colors_t *col);
```

The type is `colors_t`. Not `enum colors_t`; there is no such type.

---

I believe the problem is understanding how `typedef` works. `typedef` creates a name for a type.

```
typedef <type> <alias>;
```

For simple types, this is pretty straight-forward. This aliases `unsigned char` as `uint8_t`.

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

For structs and enums it's easy to get confused.

```
typedef enum {
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN2,
} colors_t;
```

The type is `enum { RED, BLUE, GREEN2 }`. The aliased name is `colors_t`.

In this case, the type has no other name; it's an anonymous `enum` which can only be referenced by `colors_t`.

You can give it a name.

```
typedef enum colors {
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN2,
} colors_t;
```

Now the same type can be referred to as `enum colors` or `colors_t`.

I recommend against doing this as it allows people to pierce the veil of encapsulation offered by a `typedef`. That is, if everyone uses `colors_t` you can change it in subtle ways behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

simply your code change to:

```
typedef enum {
  RED,
  BLUE,
  GREEN2,
} colors_t;

void get_color(colors_t *col)
{
    /// get_color body  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     colors_t col;
     get_color(&col); 

    return 0;
}
```